# GiLab - is it possible to get job id of the project which was executed 4 days ago through GitLab API

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

**we have scheduled pipeline executed once every day.
With this setup, i would like to know if its possible to get job id[successful] of the project which was executed 4 days ago through GitLab API**

[image]

Comment: I mean. You can [list all pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines) for a project then [list all jobs for a pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs) and find which ones are successful, sure. Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not: the [GitLab Pipeline API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-single-pipeline) only list, for a single pipeline, its latest state.

It does not list past execution occurrences.
And no [audit events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/audit_events.html) would reflect those past executions either.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation: In GitLab 13.9 and later, pipeline API endpoint can include retried jobs in the response with `include_retried` set to true.